# Errors when starting vim with the Quramy/tsuquyomi plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I use the `Quramy/tsuquyomi` plugin on my laptop and everything is working well. Today I installed it on my desktop (macOS Sierra the same as on the laptop) and I get the errors when starting the vim:

`Error detected while processing /Users/username/.vim/bundle/tsuquyomi/plugin/tsuquyomi.vim:
line   38:
E806: using Float as a String
E116: Invalid arguments for function get(g:, 'tsuquyomi_waittime_after_open', 0.01)
E15: Invalid expression: get(g:, 'tsuquyomi_waittime_after_open', 0.01)
Press ENTER or type command to continue`

I compared the output of the `vim --version` and it seems like everything is the same.

`VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep  3 2017 18:35:35)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-1050
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminal
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +terminfo
+byte_offset     -gettext         -mzscheme        +termresponse
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +textobjects
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +timers
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +title
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xpm
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xsmp
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          -xterm_save
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1

Linking: clang   -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -mmacosx-version-min=10.12 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.0/lib/perl5/5.26.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc -F/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks -framework Python   -lruby.2.4.1 -lobjc`

Also, I verified that the version of `Quramy/tsuquyomi` is the same as on my laptop.

Does anyone have an idea how these errors may be fixed?

Comment: try issue tracker of tsuquyomi

Comment: Yep, I've already created a ticket but it seems like something is missing on my desktop because on the laptop everything works well.

Comment: OK, I created a pull request. So, if I change the floating point numbers with `str2float("0.01")` the error goes away and the `:TsuDefinition` starts working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the problem was in the floating point numbers:

`get(g:, 'tsuquyomi_waittime_after_open', 0.01)`

While the plugin `+float` is included to the build the error still occurs. To **fix** this you can just replace all floating point numbers with `str2float("0.01")`:

`get(g:, 'tsuquyomi_waittime_after_open', str2float("0.01"))`

Also, I posted the pull request and it seems like the changes have been merged: https://github.com/Quramy/tsuquyomi/pull/178